# Change component state after application state is updated

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a parent component header:

It has a state:

```
    this.state = {modalIsOpen : false, user:{username:'', password:''}}
```

This stateful container has a child dumb component "popup" . This popup component calls an action which makes an API call.

I want this `modalIsOpen`(component state) to change after the API call is successful/ application state has been updated.

Basically, It's a login popup that should close once the user succesfully logged in.

Would it be ideal to move this state `modalIsIsOpen` to application state instead? Not sure. Please help.

Code:

```
class HeaderPage extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props);
        this.state = {modalIsOpen : false, user:{username:'', password:''}}
        this.toggleModal = this.toggleModal.bind(this);
        this.onLogin = this.onLogin.bind(this);
    }

  toggleModal(event){
    this.setState({modalIsOpen: !this.state.modalIsOpen});
  }

  onLogin(loginType){
   this.props.actions.loginAction(this.state.user.username, this.state.user.password, loginType, [] , "");
  }

}
}
```

`onLogin` function dispatches the actionand I want `this.toggleModal`to be called if the dispatch action was successful

Comment: Show all the relevant code: container component, popup component, redux reducer,...

Comment: @luboskrnac: Updated

Comment: To inspect your FLUX flow you need to post also reducer, action and component that maps HeaderPage to Redux store.